How can I animate a button without moving the text within?
I have a button to which I applied a costant, rotating animation.
@keyframes rotateinf {
  from { transform: rotate(  0deg); }
   to  { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}

The problem is: the child text gets the animation applied too.
I managed to make a cheap workaround for this problem, I created a  element and set the position to absolute, placing it directly on top of the button with top and right attributes.
The imptxt class just establishes the font.
<span class="imptxt" style="position: absolute;z-index: 10; color: black; top:40%; right:44%; pointer-events: none;"
  >
  All about
</span>
<span class="imptxt" style="position: absolute;z-index: 10; color: black; top:48%; right:48%; pointer-events: none;"
  >
  me
</span>
<button id="trns" class="buttonrot" onmousedown="redirect()"></button>

The buttonrot class is the following:
padding: 200px ;
  border-radius: 50px;
  z-index: 9;
  animation:fadeintop 1s ease-in-out, rotateinf 10s linear infinite 1s;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  overflow: hidden;
  transform-origin: center;

This is the result (.gif):

Is there an actual and better way to make the text stay still and apply the rotating animation on the button?
Code snippet:


.buttonrot {
  padding: 200px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  z-index: 9;
  animation: fadeintop 1s ease-in-out, rotateinf 10s linear infinite 1s;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  overflow: hidden;
  transform-origin: center;
}

@keyframes rotateinf {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
<span class="imptxt" style=" position: absolute;z-index: 10; color: black; top:40%; right:44%; pointer-events: none;">All about</span>
<span class="imptxt" style="position: absolute;z-index: 10; color: black; top:48%; right:48%; pointer-events: none;">me</span>
<button id="trns" class="buttonrot" onmousedown="redirect()"></button>




Put the text in a span inside the button and the reverse the animation on the span


.buttonrot {
  padding: 50px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  animation: rotateinf 10s linear infinite;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.buttonrot span {
  display: inline-block;
  animation: rotateinf 10s linear reverse infinite;
}

@keyframes rotateinf {
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
<button id="trns" class="buttonrot" onmousedown="redirect()"><span>All About Me</span></button>




Seems to make the text slightly blurry for me

Thanks! It looks like it works :)
Can't believe the answer was so simple...

I highly recommend to keep form elements' markup as "unopinionated" as possible:
Referring to your first approach:
<span class="imptxt" style="position: absolute;z-index: 10; color: black; top:40%; right:44%; pointer-events: none;"
  >
  All about
</span>
<span class="imptxt" style="position: absolute;z-index: 10; color: black; top:48%; right:48%; pointer-events: none;"
  >
  me
</span>
<button id="trns" class="buttonrot" onmousedown="redirect()"></button>

When separating the button text "All about me" by adding these as separate <span> elements you run into accessibility issues as visually-impaired users using a screen-reader won't get a descriptive text for the <button> element itself.
Another approach could be to keep the <button> as it is and prepend an absolutely positioned (and eventuelly animated/rotated) pseudo-element via CSS :before like so:


*{
  box-sizing:border-box;
}

.buttonrot{
  font-size:2em;
  line-height:1.2em;
  color:inherit;
  aspect-ratio: 1;
  position:relative;
  width: 200px;
  
  /* force line-break by horizontal padding */
  padding: 0 1em;
  
  /* center content horizontally and vertically */
  display:inline-flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items:center;
  
  /* reset default button styles*/
  appearance:none;
  background:none;
  border:none;
  cursor: pointer;
  
  /* just for illustration */
  outline: 1px dotted #000;
  
}

/* rotating background */
.buttonrot:before{
  content:'';
  position:absolute;
  inset:0;
  background:#ddd;
  border: 2px solid #999;
  z-index:-1;
  border-radius:10px;
  transform-origin: center;
  animation: rotateinf 5s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes rotateinf {
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
<p style="text-align:center;">
  <button class="buttonrot">All about me</button>
</p>



Basically we're not rotating the button itself but instead rotate a background pseudo-element. This way we don't need a counter-rotation to make the text-content appear unrotated – it is in fact not rotated at any time.

The problem is: the child text gets the animation applied too.

In fact we're changing the previous "parent-child" relation to a sibling-relation (OK – the :before pseudo-element would actually be a "pseudo-older-sibling" and the button text is a text node ... I think you get the gist =)
Default button styles
Especially iOS safari is infamous for introducing opinionated default styles for buttons and other form elements. So a slight style-reset like appearance:none can help to get a more consistent cross-browser styling.
Other benefits:

we can reduce the amount of animations that may eventually lead to performance issues on less performant devices.
we can easily re-style the buttons to a more minimalistic/default design without the need to change the HTML structure
the button itself could be animated separately (e.g by a "fly-in" transition) without complicting the rotation animation.



* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

p,
h3 {
  text-align: center;
}

body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.buttonrot {
  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: 2em;
  line-height: 1.2em;
  color: inherit;
  aspect-ratio: 1;
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  /* force line-break by horizontal padding */
  padding: 0 1em;
  /* center content horizontally and vertically */
  display: inline-flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  /* reset default button styles*/
  appearance: none;
  background: none;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}


/* rotating background */

.buttonrot:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  inset: 0;
  background: #ddd;
  border: 2px solid #999;
  z-index: -1;
  border-radius: 10px;
  transform-origin: center;
  animation: rotateinf 5s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes rotateinf {
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
<p>
  <button class="buttonrot">All about me</button>
</p>

<p>
  <a class="buttonrot">All about me</a>
</p>

<h3>Regular button</h3>
<p style="text-align:center;">
  <button>All about me</button>
</p>




You can even use the ::after property to achieve what you want, without any additional element.


.buttonrot {
  padding: 50px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  animation: rotateinf 10s linear infinite;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.buttonrot::after {
  content: attr(data-text);
  display: inline-block;
  animation: rotateinf 10s linear reverse infinite;
}

@keyframes rotateinf {
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
<button id="trns" class="buttonrot" onmousedown="redirect()" data-text="About Me"></button>



